# Pursuing M2 in mathematics after Masters from India

Tags: mathematics, masters, india, france

I am a master's student (5 year coursework, with a 1 year thesis) in Pure Mathematics in Indian Institute of Science Education and Research, Kolkata in my prefinal year. I wish to continue in academics and hope to pursue a PhD in future.

As I understand the PhD system in USA is in the form of a grad school, where you first do around 1-2 years of coursework before starting your full-scale research. As my background stands right now, I would be glad to delve into some more advanced coursework before starting research in a full-fledged manner. So I understand, the PhD system in USA is better for me.

I have also searched a bit on the M2 degree in mathematics in France mainly in IMJ-PRG, which allows for starting directly from the M2 coursework without having a M1 coursework. Now if I want to do a PhD in Europe, and especially in France, I think doing a M2 before going for a PhD is a better option for me.

But, I am not at all getting any detailed information of the feasibility of this second option, as the websites of the French institutes seem to be a little less user friendly.

My primary interest is particularly in Operator Algebras and Non Commutative Geometry, but I would glad to explore some other related fields in Mathematics as well.

I would be happy if someone can provide some assistance regarding this M2 and PhD in France, and also whether there are any scholarships for M2 for Indian students, how is the atmosphere for international students there, and also about the medium of instruction. Further, if anyone has any guidance for these particular research areas in France, I would be pleased to hear them.

I would like a clear idea of whether it is even possible for an Indian student who is not comfortable with the French language to sustain there?

In particular, I would like to know the leading research groups in Functional Analysis, Operator Theory/Operator Algebras and Non Commutative Geometry working in France, which universities are best for doing a M2 as a precursor to a PhD with the medium of instruction being English. Lastly, what are the chances of getting a PhD straightway in France after completing M2?

Thanks.

Comment: This looks like a good question, but could be made better by asking specific, concrete questions in the last paragraph. Opinion-based questions or questions asking to list resources are generally considered off-topic here.

Comment: @GoodDeeds Thank you for your comment, I will make the necessary changes.